# Label выходит за рамки

Tags: html, css

Label выходит за рамки div-блока, сдвигая контент. А не должен. Как исправить?

Красной стрелкой отмечена граница дива, за которую переходит лейбл.

[image: alt]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Помогло display: block;